# Tikz - What is the interval in which the value of `rand` lies within?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to put two object randomly in a shape, the presence of first object is approximately 50% , and also the same for the second object. So this is why i need to use the `rand` value.

For example I will try to test if the value of `rand` is greater than `0.5*RAND_MAX` then put object one, else put object two.

So the question is: **What is the interval in which the value of `rand` lies within?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Between -1 and 1, distributed uniformly.

See section 89.3.6 *Pseudo random functions* of the TikZ manual for descriptions of the (pseudo-)random number generators.